# Query issue in bulk file

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to query the data from the .log file. All schema is perfectly same as the file, but still my query gives a response that no row is effected. The following is my .log file structure:

`date-time,client-ip,client-hostname,server-ip,server-hostname,source-context,connector-id,source,event-id,internal-message-id,message-id,recipient-address,recipient-status,total-bytes,recipient-count,related-recipient-address,reference,message-subject,sender-address,return-path,message-info,directionality,tenant-id,original-client-ip,original-server-ip,custom-data
2017-08-23T00:00:08.631Z,10.10.30.112,xyz.domain.COM,172.16.0.25,ISIL1,08D4E23F10F7AE79;2017-08-23T00:00:05.760Z;0,ISB\Default ISBEX,SMTP,RECEIVE,702862,<secureMailer.d-347bf50db40440f6bbed36d4c4602181@horizonblue.com>,sasasda@xyz.COM;asadad@xyz.COM;mubashar@yxz.COM,134,3,Secure Message Delivery,secureMailer@horizonblue.com,secureMailer@horizonblue.com,0cI: ,Originating,15.0.30.5,15.1.0.20,S:PurportedSender=Horizon_ACH@horizonblue.com;S:FirstForestHop=as.xyz.COM`

Following is my Sql schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTest]
(
  [date-time] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [client-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [client-hostname] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [server-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [server-hostname] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [source-context] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [connector-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [source] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [event-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [internal-message-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [message-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [recipient-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [recipient-status] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [total-bytes] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [recipient-count] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [related-recipient-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [reference] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [message-subject] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [sender-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [return-path] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [message-info] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [directionality] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [tenant-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [original-client-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [original-server-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
  [custom-data] VARCHAR(max) NULL
)

  Bulk
      Insert LogTest
      From 'C:\Users\zz\Desktop\asy.log'
      with
      (
      Fieldterminator = ',',

      Rowterminator = '/t'
      )
```

Comment: SQL-Server != MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data contains different number of columns per row. row one, the headers, contains 26 columns while the second row, the data contains 22 columns only. Hence, if you add four more columns to the second row and accept the default RowTerminator, your code is OK.

```
date-time,client-ip,client-hostname,server-ip,server-hostname,source-context,connector-id,source,event-id,internal-message-id,message-id,recipient-address,recipient-status,total-bytes,recipient-count,related-recipient-address,reference,message-subject,sender-address,return-path,message-info,directionality,tenant-id,original-client-ip,original-server-ip,custom-data
2017-08-23T00:00:08.631Z,10.10.30.112,xyz.domain.COM,172.16.0.25,ISIL1,08D4E23F10F7AE79;2017-08-23T00:00:05.760Z;0,ISB\Default ISBEX,SMTP,RECEIVE,702862,<secureMailer.d-347bf50db40440f6bbed36d4c4602181@horizonblue.com>,sasasda@xyz.COM;asadad@xyz.COM;mubashar@yxz.COM,134,3,Secure Message Delivery,secureMailer@horizonblue.com,secureMailer@horizonblue.com,0cI: ,Originating,15.0.30.5,15.1.0.20,S:PurportedSender=Horizon_ACH@horizonblue.com;S:FirstForestHop=as.xyz.COM,23,24,25,26
```

```
create TABLE #LogTest
(
[date-time] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[client-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[client-hostname] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[server-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[server-hostname] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[source-context] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[connector-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[source] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[event-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[internal-message-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[message-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[recipient-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[recipient-status] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[total-bytes] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[recipient-count] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[related-recipient-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[reference] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[message-subject] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[sender-address] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[return-path] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[message-info] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[directionality] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[tenant-id] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[original-client-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[original-server-ip] VARCHAR(max) NULL,
[custom-data] VARCHAR(max) NULL
)

  Bulk
      Insert #LogTest
      From 'C:\test.log'
      with
      (
      Fieldterminator = ','
--      ,Rowterminator = '/r/n'
      )

select * from #LogTest
```

UPDATE

If some rows are nulls, then you may Bulk Insert into a temporary one-column table before the actual table. from the temp table ready only the non-null rows, parse through the columns and output them to the actual table.

```
Create table #Temp (LongColumn Varchar(max))
BULK INSERT #Temp FROM 'C:\Test.Log';

with tmp as(
    select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null)) as RowNo, 
            LongColumn 
    from #Temp as a
    WHERE a.LongColumn is NOT NULL
    ), cols as(
    select  a.RowNo
            , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by RowNo order by (select null)) as ColNo
            , b.value
    from tmp as a
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT(a.LongColumn, ',') as b
)insert into #LogTest
select 
        [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]
        ,[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]
        ,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26]
from
(
  select RowNo, value, ColNo
  from cols
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for ColNo in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]
        ,[11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20]
        ,[21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26])
) p
order by p.RowNo
;
```

Comment: i have one more issue now some of my row have Null values i want to remove all rows with NULL values???

Comment: @ali, if some rows are null i.e. one null column instead of 26 columns, then you may need to read your file into one column table first, from this table, filter-out the null rows and parse the valid rows into their columns. this will be little easier if columns are of fixed length.