# remove all NULL valued rows from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[My sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357409/query-issue-in-bulk-file)  working fine but i have another issue some rows in my table have NULL values. i want to remove all NULL valued rows. Any recommendations?

Comment: you can use where is not null

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete them from the table?

Comment: In your other question you're using SQL-Server. Why have you tagged this question for MySQL? Don't you understand the difference?

Comment: Every column in your table is `NULL`able, so you could technically leave the `NULL`valued rows in place, and simply filter them out when you do a `SELECT`?

Answer (score 15):

Delete statement should work

```
DELETE FROM your_table 
WHERE your_column IS NULL;
```

In case of multi column NULL check, I suggest using `COALESCE`

```
DELETE FROM your_table 
WHERE COALESCE (your_column1, your_column2, your_column3 ) IS NULL;
```

Comment: And, if you want to remove every row which contains a `NULL` anywhere, then you would simply extend the above: `DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_column1 IS NULL OR your_column2 IS NULL OR ...`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete a row where all columns values are null then use following query to delete:

```
    DELETE FROM your_table 
    where your_column1 IS NULL 
    AND your_column2 IS NULL 
    AND your_column3 IS NUL;
```

But if you want to delete a row where any column value is null then use following query to delete:

```
    DELETE FROM your_table 
    where your_column1 IS NULL 
    OR your_column2 IS NULL 
    OR your_column3 IS NUL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by filtering out columns you don't need, want, or will not use.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table
```

Then to remove the `null` values from your queries, use the `IS NOT NULL` command. Remember, `null` values can also be zeros, depending on how your tables and the data formats have been set up. In the example below, assume `column2` is a number format.

```
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 > 0 AND column3 IS NOT NULL
```